# How to preserve lldb session between builds

Tags: c++, makefile, lldb

I want to know if there's a way I don't have to exit lldb and restart it once I recompile my code. This way I don't have to set the breakpoints again.

Answer (score 4):

You should not have to restart lldb.  When you do a `run` after having recompiled your code, lldb will check whether any of your binaries have changed and automatically read in the new info, reset your breakpoints as appropriate and continue on.  This is convenient not just because you don't have to reset your breakpoints, but because lldb doesn't have to reparse all the system libraries your program loads, which presumably have not changed, so subsequent "run"'s are much faster.

Note, BTW, if you do have to quit & restart lldb for other reasons, you can use the `breakpoint write` and `breakpoint read` commands to save and restore your breakpoints, so you don't have to manually re-add them.